# Javascript Kendo JS UI Grid . Implementation of this grid row by row

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a requirement to put Kendo Grid in my freemarker template. I have row data for the table. For example

```
<table ... >
<#list rows as row>
<tr ... >
<td>
${row[header]!?html}
</td>
</tr>
</#list>
</table>
```

So each row gets printed in a table

However kendo requires the data to be supplied in Javascript [here](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index) . I do not see a way out to have kendo ui js grid implemented here instead of the traditional table.

If I did any mistake in my post, please let me know and I will correct it.

Kind Regards,

Comment: It should work by initializing over a `<table>` as well, check [this out](https://dojo.telerik.com/UDOPoROG).

Comment: Can you please help me provide a documentation site for the current sample. Thanks

Comment: I create it by my own, but I've found [this doc](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/overview#using-an-html-table) that can be useful.